# MySQL workbench: Check constrain in trigger

Tags: triggers, mysql-workbench, check-constraints

So i have created this table in MySQL Workbench called **iOwe**. It has a column called **Pass(Y/N)** on which i'd like to have a check constrain incorporated, which takes only the values **"Y"** or **"N"**. I understand that check constrains don't work on MySQL, and that is why there are triggers (please correct me if I am wrong). Could you please help me to create one, if that is the case, or tell me how to go about creating a check constrain, if possible. i Googled the same question, but nothing helped me so far.

Your help is greatly appreciated.

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use an ENUM datatype for the Y/N column to only accept "Y" and "N". MySQL will not accept any other value for this column then. See the [MySQL documentation for ENUM](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/enum.html) for details.